# How to create a Horizintal menu using CSS, and showing a div for an item when the item clicked

Tags: css, html

I want to show a div below the items in the horizontal menu, when I click on an item a div appears below the menu and starts where the item starts.
(I am not asking about how to show the DIV, only how to position it below the menu item)

```
<ul class="googleTab">
    <li class="active">item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
        <li>item4</li>
        <li>item5</li>
</ul>
```

and the following `css` to make the style of horizontal menu

```
ul.googleTab                {
    direction: rtl;
    background: #848383;
    padding:0 5px;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#3366cc;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(0% 100% 90deg,#f5f5f5, #ffffff);
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#f5f5f5));
}
ul.googleTab li {
    float:right;
    padding:7px 8px;
    border-top:solid 2px #bad3ea;   
         border-left-width:1px;
      border-left-color:#eee;
      border-left-style:solid;
}
ul.googleTab li.active{
    border-top: solid 3px #1a54e1;
    color:#363636;
    font-weight:bold;

}
ul.googleTab li:hover   {
    background:#e4ebf8;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could place the item inside a `ul` inside the `li` instead of using a `div` like

```
<ul>
<li>
<ul><li></li></ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

then `position:absolute;` the embedded `<ul>` and push it off the page to hide then bring back with `js` and position where you want it with `top:` and `left:`

Answer (score 0):

Put a div under your menu-ul. This new dic holds all content divs for your menu. Then you just blend in, toggle or display the needed div.

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>content1</li>
    <li>content2</li>
  <ul>
</div>

<div id="contentwrapper">
  <div id="content1" style="display:block;"></div>
  <div id="content1" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
```

Depending on the list item clicked you change all content divs to display:none and then the needed div to display:block.

Comment: oh, just have seen, that it is not quite sure what you mean. Are you talking about a box for a submenu or for tabbing?

Comment: Yes, something like this, when I click on the item the div appears but it starts in the same (x) as the item exits

Comment: What do you mean by "it starts in the same(x) as the item exits"?

Comment: x : x-axis , I mean in both item and div have same left shift value

Comment: if you want them to display directly under the menu points, then integrate the divs in the list items. <li>content1 <div id="content1"></div></li>

Comment: !!! I don't want to display the div inside the item, I want it under the item directly !!!!